# Random loss of three reputation points

Tags: support

I understand that 3 reputation points is nothing, but I randomly lost three reputation points and under my reputation in my account it does not say why I lost these three points. Does anybody know why I would lose three points? It seems very awkward, because usually you lose 2 points, 5 points, 10 points or etc. but not an odd number(except for 5).

Comment: Did you down vote any questions? Those cost 1 point each.

Comment: I do not recall doing so, but it could be very plausible.

Comment: @JonCuster I think you mean answers, not questions. :-) At any rate, Benichiwa, your profile only shows 1 downvote, so unless caching has really messed up, it's not the case.

Comment: @HDE226868 - Good point.  I blame general confusion and bureaucratically-induced memory loss...

Comment: @JonCuster Always shift the blame to the bureaucracy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because the [community](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) deleted [one of your questions](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/175196/2451) with 1 upvote (+5 rep. pts.) and 1 downvote (-2 rep. pts.), leading to a net change of -3 rep. pts.

More specifically, the question was deleted automatically because it was closed, had no net upvotes, and had not been edited for 9 days prior to the deletion. For more details see [this thread](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92006). (Hat tip: Emilio Pisanty.)

Comment: More specifically, the question was deleted automatically because it was closed, had no net upvotes, and had not been edited for 9 days prior to the deletion. For more details see [this thread](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/enable-automatic-deletion-of-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year/92006#92006).